# Some letters on gnome-terminal can't be typed by specific user

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, xterm

I have a very strange problem on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I can't use some letters like `r` and `i` in `gnome-terminal`.

**Note:** when my <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is on I can type `R` and `I` in terminal. The problem on my terminal is for just these two letters when in lowercase. For  example I can't use the `rm` command.

#### UPDATE #1

I used:

```
$ sudo su
```

Now as the root user I can type `r` and `i`.

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Try using a different keyboard and see if it's a hardware issue with your keyboard, is where I'd start first. Get a friends keyboard to confirm if you don't have an extra.

Comment: I used other keyboar.. you see r and i can be used in firefox or chrome.... but on terminal it is not possibble

Comment: When I copy paste gnome-terminal to remove this is output on my terminal: `apt-get emove gnome-temnal`

Comment: I found sth [HERE](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/v-key-stops-working-104755/)... but I don't know whats he did

Comment: I put the answer in answer part

Comment: Good find. In 2 days you can mark that as the accepted A so others know this worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I decided to activate tab completion in Python's interactive mode.

So I added the following lines to `/home/user/.inputrc`:

```
import rlcompleter, readline
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
```

So when I rebooted my machine the keys `r` and `i` from `import`  and `readline` effected on my keyboard.